# Why doesn't spinner get removed after reloading UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

Im populating a tableview from core data right from viewWillAppear.  I also add a UIActivityIndicator to be created and animating.  After fetching the data and sorting it, I call to stopAnimating.  But the spinner fails to be removed.

Here is the relevant code:

```
-(void)sort{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
    sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES] autorelease];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray;
    sortedArray = [self.annotationsToSort sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    self.annotationsToSort = [(NSArray*)sortedArray mutableCopy];

    //[self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.5];
}

- (void)reloadData {
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    //set activity bar #UPDATETOIPAD
    [spinner stopAnimating];
}
```

The spinner appears but doesn't get removed.

The lifecycle of the tableview is like this:

1. viewDidLoad creates spinner and adds it to self.view
2. viewWillAppear calls loadRecordsFromCoreData
3. loadRecordsFromCoreData fetches and checks if data returned into array is = 0 and if so, displays alert, otherwise, dispatches to main queue populateLocationsToSort.
4. populateLocationsToSort does some work and calls sort.
5. sort does what you see above and then reloads the data.

Comment: Do you have the hidesWhenStopped property set to YES?

Answer (score 0):

You call the following code after your sort :

```
[self.tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.5];
```

You are performing reloadData on self.tableView instead of self (which calls reloadData on your tableView + hides the spinner)

try calling

```
[self performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.5];
```

and make sure your spinner hidesWhenStopped property is set to YES